# What is the punishment for violating the Treaty of Algeron?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9

Both the Romulans and the Federation have regularly violated the Treaty when it suits them. Starfleet has obviously developed and manufactured cloaking/stealth technology and the Romulans make regular excursions across the Neutral Zone. They obviously aren't declaring all-out war, so what penalties or sanctions have been imposed for violations?

-edit added for clarity-

Has either side ever 'punished' their own people for any violations of the Treaty?

Comment: That’s a paddlin’.

Comment: I felt that my answer was pretty comprehensive, at least within the bounds of what we see in the shows. Is there anything else you'd like to see before considering an acceptance?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Governmental Punishments

Mutually agreed treaties between sovereign powers (for example [this one](http://news.findlaw.com/cnn/docs/korea/kwarmagr072753.html)) don't usually have *penalties* attached unless they've been imposed on one party by another, typically following a military defeat.

Since both the United Federation of Planet and the Romulan Star Empire agreed the 'Treaty of Algeron' in good faith if either party intentionally [broke the treaty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty#Ending_treaty_obligations), it might constitute a justifiable [Act of War](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_belli) but that's it.

For the record, the full terms of the Treaty of Algeron have never been codified in any of the trek shows or films (or even the EU books) so all of this is pure guesswork.

### Individual Punishments

As regards '*individual*' punishments for breaches of the Treaty; Commander Riker and Admiral Pressman were both placed under arrest at the end of the "[Pegasus Incident](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Pegasus_%28episode%29)". Apparently Riker and Picard suffered no further punishment for their actions, presumably because Riker claimed to be young and stupid and Picard claimed exigent circumstances.

The TNG Short Story : [Orphans](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Orphans_%28SNW%29) reveals that Admiral Pressman was ultimately court-martialed for his actions and dishonourably discharged. He subsequently became a senior member of Section-31.

On the other side of the fence, Commander [Tomalak](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Tomalak) **repeatedly** violated the Neutral Zone and evidently suffered no punishment by the Romulan Empire.

Comment: Yes, usually treaties do stipulate or incorporate a "If this, that" clause. 'Cause-effect'. 'Action-reaction'. What I'm looking for is the "that" part of the clause. We don't know what the Treaty 'specifically' said or it's verbiage because we've never been shown it. But we can see any effects or reactions derived from violations that would give us the answer.

Comment: As Ribbentrop said, treaties are "pieces of paper." Where superpowers are involved, simply breaking a treaty doesn't tend to lead to much of anything. Look at the worldwide "meh, maybe some sanctions" that the world has responded to Russia's actions in Ukraine with. It takes both an especially egregious, and, more importantly, highly **public** violation of a treaty before any punishments are considered. None of the various violations of the treaty by the Federation or Romulus constituted that, at least before *Nemesis*.

Comment: @Morgan No, treaties do *not* typically have such clauses. Look at the example Richard provided in his answer, or any of the dozens upon dozens of treaty texts you can look up and read in full -- overwhelmingly they do not have penalties, just lists of "do this, don't do that" etc. Treaty violations are considered within judicial and/or executive contexts of the party wronged, or of a "world court"-type body (although none seems to exist in *Trek*), and as Richard says in his answer can be seen as an act of aggression/war -- which is exactly how they're treated in the show. That's your answer.

Comment: @Morgan - The Romulans seem pretty confident they can use the treaty as an excuse to hold the Enterprise hostage and kidnap the crew. Neither side seems to want an actual fight though...

Comment: @JamesSheridan So you're saying that the Treaty of Algeron is simply a gentlemen's agreement with no teeth between non-gentlemen and can be violated at whim by either party and that no sanctions or consequences have ever happened within the Star Trek universe as a result of such 'violations'?

Comment: @Richard It seems so. Beyond a bit of mean-mugging from the Federation, the Romulans don't seem too concerned.

Comment: @Morgan - That's precisely how treaties between superpowers work.

Comment: @Morgan: Richard is right. I used to work for DFAT (Department of Foreign Affairs and Trade) here in Australia. We caught other countries breaking treaties with us all the time (no, none of you can have details) and we did a whole lot of nothing in response. As I said, the violation has to be both serious and public; Australia was forced to grovel to Indonesia after our current mental midget of a Prime Minister ordered several of our ships across the Indon border, then stupidly let it slip in a press conference. Between superpowers, the rules are even less binding.

Comment: I don't recall Picard being arrested in the episode nor find a source stating so? Do you have a reference handy I could be missing?

Comment: @JonClements - You're right. He's the one doing the arresting and although he used the phasing cloak, he seems to have gotten away with it scot free.

Comment: I think it was pretty easy to use Pressman as a scapegoat, especially since Riker came forward. Command probably would have wanted to just classify and wash their hands clean of the whole thing.

Comment: @PointlessSpike if I recall correctly - Pressman was acting with someone high up in Starfleet Security well aware/in favour/authorising his actions - so he'd have definitely been a good scapegoat to protect that person and project - all the evidence could probably be twisted to show him going a bit AWOL (although Riker was told by Pressman that SS was involved - so depends what evidence he gave -if any). What with maintaining the cover-up, Riker could just claim "I was just following the Admiral's orders" and with Picard's sway in Starfleet - I'd guess it blew over quickly and fairly silently.

Comment: Yeah, whatever the situation with the higher-ups it would be hushed-up. As shown by the reaction to Section 31, people just don't wanna think about this stuff.

Answer (score 6):

Apparently both Admiral Pressman and Commander Riker had been arrested, thrown in the brig and charged with 'violating the Treaty of Algeron'. Riker was subsequently set free by Picard but there is no further word about what happened to Pressman. Obviously, violation of the Treaty does carry some sort of legal punishment.

Here's some of the backstory concerning the Pegasus Saga:

> The phasing cloaking device was developed by a secret group in Starfleet Security in the 2350s. An expansion on the more traditional cloaking device, it was designed to phase sequence the structure of matter and energy to such a rate that it was possible to allow any vessel utilizing the device to pass through normal matter in the phased state. A direct violation of the Treaty of Algeron, which banned cloaking technology aboard Federation starships, the phasing cloak was first tested aboard the USS Pegasus in 2358, under the command of Captain Erik Pressman.
>
> A Judge Advocate General's investigation into the mutiny aboard the Pegasus was initiated, but, in order to conceal the illegal test, Starfleet Intelligence classified the file. 
>   In 2370 Pressman, now an admiral at Starfleet Intelligence, boarded the USS Enterprise-D and mounted a mission to retrieve the phasing cloak.
>
> Deciding not to continue to aid Pressman in the illegal activity, Riker revealed the existence of the cloaking device to Captain Picard.
>
> After some adventures extracting themselves from the asteroid both Admiral Pressman and Commander Riker were subsequently taken into custody for their respective roles in the illegal experiment. Picard orders Pressman be arrested, and charged with violating the Treaty of Algeron. Riker points out that he too will have to be arrested, and Picard reluctantly agrees. 
>   Pressman notes angrily that he has a lot of friends at Starfleet Command – Picard quietly muses to himself that he will need them.
>   (ENT: "These Are the Voyages..."; TNG: "The Pegasus")

Comment: They're being punished by the UFP  themselves, not the same thing

Comment: @Richard Are you splitting hairs now big dog? Being punished for violating the Treaty, no matter by whom, is still being punished for violating the Treaty is it not?

Comment: They're being punished not for violating the treaty but for disobeying a standing order; e.g. that Starfleet don't make political policy. That's not what the OP was asking. He was wanting to know if the UFP/Romulans suffered punishment for their repeated breaches.

Comment: @Richard: Morgan is the OP. You're not wrong though.

Comment: @JamesSheridan - oops.I didn't spot that :-)

Comment: @Richard -'The Starfleet standing order is that you can't violate the Treaty of Algeron. If you do violate the Treaty you will be punished, not for violating the Treaty mind you, but for violation the Starfleet standing order that forbids violating the Treaty.'? Maybe it's me but that sure sounds like a bit of parsing and hair splitting. Are you familiar with the concept of "but for"? 'But for' the Treaty of Algeron there would be no standing orders forbidding the violation of the Treaty of Algeron. Just sayin'

Comment: Imagine the look on the face of the Warbirds captain when the Enterprise decloaked near them.